# How do I get all the institutions in my SQL query in oracle with inner join?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to write a query in `oracle SQL`, first I am trying to edit a profile, so I want to change the institution that the user previously select it, but for that I must get all the institutions from a table named `institution` (`id_institution`, `name_institution`),

```
select user.user_name, institution.name_institution from user 
inner join institution_has_user on user.id_user = institution_has_user.user_id_user 
inner join institution on institution_has_user.institution_id_institution = institution.id_institution  
where user = 'george';
```

But all I get It is the data that he register, and I want all the institutions, so I can fill a select html, just for editing purposes

Comment: A little sample data would go a long way.  Your joins look fine, so without context it will be hard to help.

Comment: this query just return a single row of data, and I want all the data from the table institution, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all the institutions from your above query, then you'll need to use an `OUTER JOIN` and move your `WHERE` criteria to your `JOIN`.  This will however return `NULL` records for the user name field where there aren't any matches which might not be what you're looking for:

```
select distinct user.user_name, institution.name_institution 
from institution 
    left join institution_has_user on institution_has_user.institution_id_institution = institution.id_institution 
    left join user on user.id_user = institution_has_user.user_id_user  
        and user.user_name = 'george';
```

Perhaps an easier alternative solution, just run two queries -- it should be perfectly fine to create a drop down list from a single select statement:

```
select name_institution 
from institution
```

Comment: thanks for answering but I need the data for creating the form, I create a list for this data , and then I create a string for the form

Comment: @bentham -- no worries, the outer join solution sounds like what you're looking for unless I misunderstood your question.  Kind regards.